# Celery retry: Can I set my own delay depending on each retry

Tags: celery, task

I 'm trying to create a retry on a celery task but every retry needs to be done after a specific delay.
Is it possible to that and how ?

for example first retry would be 5 seconds, next one 25, next one 125

```
@app.task(bind=true, max_retries=10, delay=5)
```